# Cache script reference with Find in Awake works, in Start doesn't

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to cache a reference to another script in Unity.

I don't understad why, in the following code, caching the reference in Start() does not work (I get a NullReferenceException) while caching the reference in Awake() works.

It was my understanding that Start() get called AFTER Awake(). But from what I see when Start() get called the object AnotherScript does not exist yet, while it exits when Awake() gets called.

What am I missing?

```
void Start()
{
    anotherscript = GameObject.Find("AnotherScript").GetComponent<AnotherScript>(); // does not work
    MyMethod();
}

void Awake()
{
    anotherscript = GameObject.Find("AnotherScript").GetComponent<AnotherScript>(); // works
}

void MyMethod()
{
    anotherscript.SomeMethod();
}
```

adasdad

Comment: GameObject named "AnotherScript" may have been destroyed in **OnEnable** method somewhere.

Comment: Script order also can come into play.

Comment: Well, from what I read in the Unity API, this method call only returns the object on "ACTIVE" game objects.  Not sure what you are doing with "AnotherScript" but are you creating them disabled on startup?

Comment: OnEnable method not used in my code

Comment: No,I'm not creating the object "AnotherScript" disabled on startup

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `AnotherScript` gameObject does not exist at the time when You are first looking for it. Or it is turned off. Or just its `AnotherScript` components is not yet attached to it. It can happen if you are creating it dynamically.

Try investigating the actual timeline: put some `Debug.Log("i am ready " + name, gameObject);` in `Awake()` and `Start()` methods of this script and of the `AnotherScript`.

Also you can explicitly reorder the execution order of Your scripts in **Edit > Project Settings > Script Execution Order** Do this only if You are certain your script is starting before some third script that creates / sets up the `AnotherScript` is starting.

Comment: Thanks, I've investigated as you suggested and discovered that in Start() I was calling MyMethod() BEFORE anotherscript variable initialization. The code I posted in the question works as expected.